# yii Bootstrap Twitter - which extention is the "right" extension?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I want use http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ in my application.

I found for yii two extensions:
http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/
http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/

Mayby is more then this 2?

Which one is better? What is difference? What with licence? My application is commercial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yii-Booster is a library that contains Yii-Bootstrap and many other Yii widgets and components.

If you just want Bootstrap your project Yii-Bootstrap will probably solve your problem, but if you want a more complete library I recommend Yii-Booster.

Example of widgets contained in Yii-Booster:

- Select2: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/
- Editable: http://vitalets.github.com/bootstrap-editable/#options
- StickyTableHeaders: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders
- BootGroupGridView: http://groupgridview.demopage.ru/
- JQueryUI Bootstrap CSS: http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/

And many other components:

- http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/components.html
- http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/json-grid.html
- http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html;

As told you in other answer, both projects use the license New BSD License.

It's all a matter of fitting your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The Yii Booster is one project based on Yii Bootstrap and have some components more.

The projects have the same source code base.

So far, the Yii Bootstrap, solved my problems, however, if you want to use some component unique of the Yii Booster, use it!

Both projects use the license [New BSD License](http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php).

More informations about the projects you will find the links below:

- [Yii Bootstrap - Extension Page](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap).
- [Yii Bootstrap - Discussion Topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/23982-extension-bootstrap/).
- [Yii Booster - Extension Page](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiibooster/).
- [Yii Booster - Discussion Topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36258-yiibooster/).

Another similar extension:  [Yii Foundation 3](http://foundation3.oakwebdev.com/?utm_source=update&utm_medium=ext-page&utm_campaign=v0.1.0).

- [Yii Foundation 3 - Extension Page](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/foundation3).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you know somebody made detail compare this extensions?

Answer (score 2):

A more up to date version of Yii-Bootstrap is [Yiistrap](http://www.getyiistrap.com). Yiistrap has also been written by the author of Yii-Bootstrap and is offered under a BSD-3-Clause license, so commercial use should be fine.

As already pointed out Yii-Booster is simply a prepackaged app with various extensions already in place. An alternative to that would be [Yii-App](https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-app) for instance. It contains fewer markup extensions but a number of developer and backend extensions that may help with basic development.